# How to get others interested in restarting a very old campaign?

Tags: system-agnostic, group-dynamics

I am a part of a pretty regular little RP group, we have played several games together, and every person has had a turn GMing on or another game. However, over time, life happens, other things get in the way, and the game often gets forgotten. So far 3 games have been lost to time, and a 4th is bordering on being dumped as well.

Personally, and this might be a flaw on my part, but I find it hard to let go of some characters - sometimes I might "re-invent" them in a way when I create a new character. But what I would really like to do is restart the old campaigns.

Some of the problems we have are:

- Our time runs on a schedule. We effectively have to "book in" when we want to hang out, and even then it's not a guarantee.
- Some players have left. Not everyone in our original group is available any more.
- It's been a *long* time since we last played any of the campaigns.

Because of this, the general level of interest has fallen rather significantly. What I have done is tried to talk to some of the group's members to see whether or not they'd be interested in running the games again, but due to the above mentioned issues, the interest isn't all that high.

The part that I'm most interested in is bringing others back to restarting the old campaigns. Most of them are ones that other people ran, so how can I try and convince them to restart their campaign(s)?

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be a RPG related issue. You asked them if they'd be interested in restarting the campaign and they're not interested. Until we have a mindcontrol stackexchange, that's really as far as you're going to get.

Comment: May I suggest http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neuro-linguistic-prog ?

Comment: I think this question is perfectly valid. As the only answer so far has demonstrated, there are approaches you can take as a GM that could reinvigorate interest.

Comment: The current answer is completely subjective. If the problem is that his ex-players simply don't have time to run games anymore, using a different system is not going to make it any better. (In fact, people might be even less motivated because they don't have the time to learn a new system.)

Comment: @Theik Its virtue is that it cites experience, making it the good kind of subjective. To a question like this, we really want answers that follow the principles in the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) article rather than untested suggestions, because so much of our topic is subjective, and meeting that bar is shown to significantly raise average answer quality enough to make even subjective questions fit our format. As for topicality: game/group management is on topic, as we're experts there.

Comment: I tend to doubt that this question will get a *good* answer, as in one that concisely and reliably solves the problem presented, but I see nothing wrong with asking and seeing if someone here surprises us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I would suggest is that **you need aim for what your friends *want*, or to be more accurate, *need*, as a change**.

Now that they're not interested in it would mean they're bored of it, so they want to do somthing else. They *need* ***improvements and changes*** that **they expect**, not only your ideas.

So try re-inventing your game that suits all of the intended players, including yourself.

This is what I have noticed in my life.

I must acknowledge that this is coming from a socially-awkward person (myself), but please take it into consideration. Speak to them about this idea before implementing it.

I hope this was helpful =)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! This is a pretty good answer (+1), though I did make some minor corrections. Anyway, if you haven’t, I recommend you check out the [Tour], and once you hit 20 rep, feel free to join the [Chat].

Comment: @KRyan thanx =)

Answer (score 5):

Try proposing a reboot with a different system.
I'm in the same situation and sometime I'm able to convince my old players to restart our abandoned games just proposing a different system.
The idea of trying something new on the familiar ground of an old world with old companions, can do the magic and revive interest and motivation in some players.